# uniformly convergence to discontinuous function.

Tags: uniform-convergence

My question is as follows

(1) is there discontinuous sequence of function $<f_n>$, uniformly converge to discontinuous function $f$?

(2) is there sequence of function $<f_n>$ which does not uniformly converge to any function(it doesn't matter that the function is continuous or discontinuous. what else!)

I tried to find those function. In my opinion, $f_n = x^n$ converge uniformly to function which value is zero except for $x$=1(but it does not converge uniformly to $f=0$. But, this example is not applicable to the question (1) because $f_n$ is continuous sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1).  I presume you mean a sequence of discontinuous functions, not a discontinuous sequence.  Yes, just take any discontinuous function $f$ and let $f_n(x) = f(x) + 1/n$.

2) Any sequence of functions that fails to converge at some point, or converges but not uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understood what you talked about (1). But, I have a question for the (2). According to your response, the sequence $f_n(x)=nx$ on $\Bbb R$, for example, is not uniformly continuous to any function. Right?

Comment: Not uniformly convergent to any function, yes.